# SQL - To compare the changes and run the set of scripts from one server to another

Tags: sql

I have a DEV Server X which is facing end customer and a QA server backend. X hadn't been updated since May and Now, I need to match it up with the QA DBs.

I am able to do the schema changes using REDGATE SQL Compare but Insert/Update scripts are pending.

Any simpler way to do this? Or Do I need to proceed manually one by one?